# How do I get value from datavaluefield and print it on a page in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net-2010

I am quite new to programming and will really appreciate if anyone can help me..Thanks

Question: My dropdown list in my web project is holding value of a person name in 'DataTextField' and it is holding person's ID in the 'DataValueField'

so if I want to print the value of the DataValueField what shall I do?

What I did:

```
Dim PersonID as String = DropDownPerson.DataValueField
Response.Write(PersonID)
```

but the above code is returning the column name and not the value of the column.

Please help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim PersonID as String = DropDownPerson.SelectedValue
```

Just to clear something up - `DataTextField` and `DataValueField` are used by the dropdown control (and databinding) to describe which fields to use as the display value and identity value for a selected row.

`SelectedValue` holds the actual value of the field named in `DataValueField` for the selected row.